# php://input as resouce AND string

Tags: php, inputstream

Whit the follow code:

```
$file = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$temp = tmpfile();
$imageSize = stream_copy_to_stream($file, $temp);
$imageDimensions = getimagesize($file); // Error here
$imageInfos = pathinfo($_GET['selected-image']);
```

I get this error
`getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given`

Because `$file` is a resource of `fopen`. How I can have a resource and a string if I can't read `php://input` twice?

---

**UPDATE**

I have tried this:

```
$file = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$tempName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '.upload');
$imageSize = fwrite(fopen($tempName, 'w+'), stream_get_contents($file));
$imageDimensions = getimagesize($tempName);
$imageInfos = pathinfo($_GET['selected-image']);

// Unlinks and other stuffs
```

The error:

```
Notice: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Read error! in
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize) only accepts string filenames, not resources, you will need to use [`tempnam()`](http://php.net/tempnam) to create a temporary file with a name that you can pass to [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize).

```
$file = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$tempName = tempnam('/var/tmp', 'img_');
$temp = fopen($tempName, 'w');
$imageSize = stream_copy_to_stream($file, $temp);
fclose($temp);
$imageDimensions = getimagesize($tempName);
```

This assumes that the user running PHP has write and read permissions to the directory `/var/tmp`, but if it doesn't you can change to a directory that the user does have r/w permissions to.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`tempnam()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) to generate your temp file, instead of `tmpfile()`. Then you have a file path which you can pass to `getimagesize()`:

```
$file = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$tempname = tempnam('.', 'img');
$tempfile = fopen($tempname, 'w+');
$imageSize = stream_copy_to_stream($file, $tempfile);
$imageDimensions = getimagesize($tempname);
$imageInfos = pathinfo($_GET['selected-image']);

// At the end of the script, you need to remember to...
fclose($tempfile);
unlink($tempname);
```

Comment: Why `tempnam();` with `$img` as second param?

Comment: @GabrielSantos Apologies, that should have been the string `'img'`, see updated answer

Comment: @GabrielSantos please show the output of `var_dump($tempName)` when you get the error

Comment: `string 'D:\Webserver\htdocs\santosidaniel\qualasuaponte\application\img9AD3.tmp' (length=71)`. But same error.

Comment: How about `var_dump(file_exists($tempName)); var_dump(is_readable($tempName));`?

Comment: `var_dump(file_exists($tempName));` and `var_dump(is_readable($tempName));` return true.